# Argument list too long from shell script

Tags: shell, unix

one case:
I wrote script on tsch that invoke other script on python.
When I invoke python script from cmd , it is OK.
When I invoke test script on tsch then I get error: Argument list too long

Another case:

```
git grep -e "alex" -- `git ls-files | grep -v 'bin'`
```

I also get error: `Argument list too long`.
What can problem and How to solve it ?

Comment: You ask "what can be the problem"? Well, probably the argument list is too long, isn't it? Did you check its length? Every shell has limits.

Comment: How can I check it ? When I run from command line, I have not problem. @arkascha

Comment: Well, how is it called? You could redirect the argument list into a file for example.

Comment: script.py > file @arkascha

Comment: No, that redirects the _output_ of the script. The error message is about the _input_ to some process. Either the script itself or something the script calls internally.

Comment: input in python script. I only want to run the script from tsch. @arkascha

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are trying to say with that comment. Please be precise in your comments...

Comment: What do you mean ? @arkascha

Comment: Did you even bother to try to understand what I wrote about the two possible situations where an argument list might be relevant?

Comment: Yes. I didn't find problem.   I only want to run the script from tsch @arkascha

Comment: Which is perfectly clear. So what is the argument list that is too long? That error message is nothing the environment makes up for fun. So where is a call to something that receives some arguments in your script? Typically such error occurs when piping the output of one command into another command, for example the result of a call to `ls` or `find`...

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

I'm not familiar with the specific `git` commands you are using and you don't seem to be replying sensibly to the questions in the comments either. I guess you probably want something like this though:

```
git ls-files | grep -v 'bin' | xargs -L 128 git grep -e "alex" --
```

**Original Answer**

The classic way to solve *"error: Argument list too long"* is with `xargs`. It can be used to repeatedly call a script whose name you provide, or `echo` if you don't provide one, with a limited number of arguments till the arguments are all consumed.

So, imagine you have a million files in a directory, then `ls *` will fail, however a simple `ls` will work. So, we can put that to use with:

```
ls | xargs -L 128
```

which will call `echo` (because we didn't provide a utility name) repeatedly with 128 filenames at a time till all are echoed.

So, you could do:

```
ls | xargs -L 128 yourScript.py
```

to call your Python script repeatedly with 128 filenames at a time. Of course you may be doing something completely different and incompatible with this technique but your answers are not very helpful so far...

Comment: how can I integrate in 'git grep command'. i.e: git grep <pattern> -- `git ls-files` @Mark Setchell

Comment: You would need to click `edit` under your original question, and show how you run that command, what a few sample output lines look like, and how they need to then be processed.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see what command you actually ran, nor what sort of output it produces... I guess the `grep -v bin` part works ok, so we can skip that, so do you run `git grep -e "alex" -- git ls-files`? What does it produce? Sorry, I am not a big user of `git`.

Comment: I got stderr "unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option" @Mark Setchell

Answer (score 0):

for somebody comes here who need to do something like this:

```sh
./shell_script.sh param1
```

but it raises error `Argument list too long` from shell script of `param1`.
I just run into this, and fix it by a workaround of using the shell variable.

```sh
# calling the PARAM1 instead of $1 in code of shell_script.sh
export PARAM1=param1 ./shell_script.sh
```

---

an example of a ruby version of transferring string to nodejs:

```rb
ENV["PARAM1"]="a_bunch_of_test_string_as_longer_as_you_can"
`node node_script.sh`
```

```js
var param1 = process.env.PARAM1;
console.log(param1);
```